# Problems with pandas_ta indicators rsi

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pandas-ta

I try to put 1 por trading strategy when rsi if > 30 and 0 if the previous period if < 30

```
data['rsi_compra'] = 1 if data.rsi > 30 & data.rsi.shift(periods = 1) < 30 else 0
```

Raise this error

> Cannot perform 'rand_' with a dtyped [float64] array and scalar of type [bool]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
data['rsi_compra'] = ((data.rsi > 30) & (data.rsi.shift(periods=1) < 30)).map(int)
```

you should keep in mind yu are working with pandas series and not a scalar value , while & operand applies to a single item in that series & using parenthesis is necessary for that purpose.

Comment: thank you the commments but the type must be float, because compare two numbers

Comment: what you mean? mapping to int is just to cast True/False to 1/0 for presentation purposes. has nothing to do with comparing

Answer (score 0):

if you simply wish to do as, if >30 is 1 one <30 as 0

```
data['rsi_compra'] = (data.rsi > 30 ).astype(int)
```

and if you want peroid as you mentioned try this

```
data['rsi_compra'] = ((data.rsi > 30) & (data.rsi.shift(periods=1) < 30)).astype(int)
```